# Legend markers not shown in matplotlib mixed scatter and line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, astronomy

I have a plot with legend which looks like
[image]

which is created with the following code

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (30 , 11))
gs = GridSpec(nrows=12, ncols=15)
gs.update(wspace = 0, hspace = 0.5)

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:12, 0:5])
#ax0.scatter(fullmergedf['td_lmass'] , fullmergedf['PAB_SFR_EX_LL_1SIGMA'] , s = 200 , marker = '+' , c = 'black')
#ax0.errorbar(fullmergedf['td_lmass'] , fullmergedf['PAB_SFR_EX2'] , yerr = fullmergedf['PAB_SFR_EX2_ERR'] , c = 'gray',  linestyle = 'None')
#ax0.scatter(fullcleardf['td_lmass'] , fullcleardf['PAB_SFR_EX2_LIMIT'] , s = 20, c = 'black')
y0 = ax0.scatter(fullmergedf['td_lmass'] , fullmergedf['PAB_SFR_EX2'] , s = 200 , c = fullmergedf['ir_UV_beta'] , cmap = 'coolwarm' , label = 'Cleri et al. 2020')
scatter0 = ax0.scatter(fullmergebaddf['td_lmass'] , fullmergebaddf['PAB_SFR_EX2'] , s = 200, c = fullmergebaddf['ir_UV_beta'] , cmap = 'coolwarm' , marker = 'D' , label = 'Marginal (1$\sigma$ - 3$\sigma$) Detections')
scatter0.set_facecolor('none')
ax0.scatter(sortedclearmergedf['td_lmass'] , sortedclearmergedf['PAB_SFR_EX2_LIMIT'] , s = 20, c = 'black' , marker = 'v' , label = '3D-HST 1$\sigma$ Limits')
scatterdots0 = ax0.scatter(sortedclearmergedf['td_lmass'] , sortedclearmergedf['PAB_SFR_EX2_LIMIT_RAND'] , s = 200, c = sortedclearmergedf['ir_UV_beta'] , cmap = 'coolwarm' , label = 'Survival Analysis')
scatterdots0.set_facecolor('none')

ax0.plot(limitdf['td_lmass'] , limitdf['ROLL_MAD'] , c = 'green' , label = 'Rolling MAD')
ax0.plot(limitdf['td_lmass'] , -limitdf['ROLL_MAD'] , c = 'green')
ax0.plot(limitdf['td_lmass'] , limitdf['ROLL_MAD_FIT_TOP'] , c = 'gray' , label = 'Rolling MAD to fit')
ax0.plot(limitdf['td_lmass'] , limitdf['ROLL_MAD_FIT_BOT'] , c = 'gray')
ax0.plot([6 , 11] , [0 , 0] , '--' , c = 'gray')
ax0.set_ylabel(r'log($SFR_{Pa\beta}$) - log($SFR_{UV}^{corr}$)')
ax0.set_xlabel(r"log$(M_*/M_{\odot})$")
ax0.axis([6.5 , 10.5 , -3 , 3])
for i in range(0, len(lmlimitall.chain), 25):
    xs = np.arange(-6,12)
    ys = lmlimitall.chain[i]['alpha'] + xs * lmlimitall.chain[i]['beta']
    ax0.plot(xs, ys, color='gray', alpha=0.03)
# ax1.plot([-2 , 2] , [np.mean(lmpabhabeta.chain['alpha']) + np.mean(lmpabhabeta.chain['beta'])*-2 , np.mean(lmpabhabeta.chain['alpha']) + np.mean(lmpabhabeta.chain['beta'])*2] , c = 'black' , label = 'm = ' + str(round(np.mean(lmpabhabeta.chain['beta']) , 2)) + r'$\pm$' + str(round(np.std(lmpabhabeta.chain['beta']), 2))  )

ax0.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.7, 0.5) , loc = 'center right')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:1,1:4])
fig.colorbar(y0,ax3,use_gridspec=True,orientation='horizontal' ,  label = r'$\beta$')
ax3.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax3.xaxis.get_label().set_verticalalignment('bottom')

plt.show()
```

The legend on the right does not show the markers for 'Marginal (1$\sigma$ - 3$\sigma$) Detections' or 'Survival Analysis'. I suspect that this has to do with the fact that I have the face color set to none for those two scatter plots. How do I get this so that it shows a hollow diamond and hollow circle respectively?

Comment: Have you tried to test your suspicion?

Comment: @mapf Yes I have. If I get rid of the .set_facecolor('none') statements then it works fine, but I need to have those points be hollow.

Comment: How about setting the facecolor to an RGBA value like (0,0,0,0), i.e., with an alpha value of zero, making it fully transparent?

Comment: @Mr.T This produces the same results as setting the face color to 'none'.

Comment: So, what does `['ir_UV_beta']` contain? A value between 0 and 1? A color name? An RGBA value? We don't know.

Comment: @Mr.T it contains `float64`s ranging from -1.9 to 4.4

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to set the `edgecolor` (`ec`) instead of the `color` (`c`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm


data = np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 10))
cmap = cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

scatter = ax.scatter(
    *data, s=10, ec=colors, marker='D', fc='none',
    label='Marginal (1$\sigma$ - 3$\sigma$) Detections'
)
ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried things similar to this, but it doesn't work with a variable edge color the way that I have it. Do you have a way that this will work when pulling different colors for each point?

Comment: Well, that wasn't clear from your post. It also works with multiple colors though.

Comment: This still is running into issues with my data which generate the colors. If I use this method with `ec = fullmergedf['ir_UV_beta']` which are is the color coding I need I get `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument:`.

Comment: Well, it's impossible to tell what is wrong without more information. This is really why you should strip down your code to the absolute minimum that still produces the error and remove everything else. We cannot run your code so we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: The column of the DataFrame I am calling for the colors contains `float64`s ranging from -1.9 to 4.4. I am not sure how else I can convey that other than giving my code as it is and what I have already said.

Comment: If all else fails, is there a way where I can just manually put a hollow diamond and circle in the legend?

Comment: And what are those floats supposed to represent?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The floats are values of a parameter called beta by which we are color coding the points.

Comment: You have to map that to a color map. How is the program supposed to know what the colors the values correspond to? The easiest thing would be to normalize the values and like I did pass it to the `cmap`.

Comment: I'm not sure what good that would do. Normalizing as you did would change the range from 0-1, but that is not what I want.

Comment: No, it changes the range *to* 0-1. You said your range is from -1.9 to 4.4. That's why you need to normalize in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, typo. That is what I meant, it changes the range from -1.9 to 4.4 to 0-1. I want it to be from -1.9 to 4.4 though.

Comment: You want that for your *data* but not for your *cmap*.

Comment: I am still confused by your suggestion, as it seems we are getting pretty far from the initial question. I have found a very clunky way to brute force a solution, but it is not very elegant at all.

Comment: I don't think so. Just give it a try. Look at my code. Try to understand how I created the colors. Print them, change them, play around with them. Try to understand why you can't just pass a bunch of floats instead. There isn't anything else I can do at this point because all the information is there. Just create your own colors from your own numbers and see what you get.